# creating ".project" file in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-management, eclipse, filenames, dotfiles

I just downloaded an eclipse .project file from outlook but was not able to find it. I figured that this might be an issue because the file does not have a name and has only an extension. thus I changed its name while saving and I was able to download the file. However, The problem now, is that I am unable to rename it back to .project. This was a huge pain. Finally, I copied an existing .project into the folder I wanted and then copied the contents from the one that I downloaded into this file by opening them in a Notepad(NPP++ for me).

I was wondering how this kind of behavior is possible in windows where a file can exist with that particular name but cannot be renamed into it. Any Ideas?

I was also looking for an easier way to accomplish the task mentioned above.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows explorer do not accept file name that include nothing before dot.

Here is a way to do that:

1. generate a foo.project file with the content you need.
2. type cmd in run box to have the command line console
3. go to the folder include foo.project
4. type command: copy foo.project .project

Then you will get the .project file.